# Alguien me puede explicar que tengo erroneo?

Tags: c++, array

Buen dia, me pusieron este problema en la escuela y no logro entender en que me equivoque, perdon si es un error muy obvio aun soy un principiante:

> El programa es utilizando arreglos unidimensionales
>
> 1.- Calcule el promedio de calificaciones por alumno, tomando en cuenta: a) El usuario determinará la cantidad de alumnos a promediar.
> b) El usuario determinará la cantidad de calificaciones por alumno.
>
> 2.- El programa deberá desplegar en pantalla el siguiente mensaje: Del alumno: _________ Las calificaciones registradas son: Calificación 1:
> _______ Calificación 2: _______ Calificación N: _______ Por lo tanto el PROMEDIO del alumno es de:__________

Mi codigo lo hice asi:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int Alumnos,Calificaciones,k=0,suma;
float promedio;
    
cout<<"Ingrese por favor el numero de estudiantes: ";
cin>>Alumnos;
    
    while(Alumnos<=0){
        cout<<"El numero de alumnos no puede ser menor o igual a 0, intentelo de nuevo."<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese por favor el numero de estudiantes: ";
        cin>>Alumnos;
    }
    
int  Datos[Alumnos];

cout<<"Ingrese por favor el numero de calificaciones por estudiante: ";
cin>>Calificaciones;
    
    while(Alumnos<=0){
        cout<<"El numero de calificaciones no puede ser menor o igual a 0, intentelo de nuevo."<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese por favor el numero de calificaciones por estudiante: ";
        cin>>Calificaciones;
    }
    
int Datos2[Calificaciones]; 

for(int i=0;i<Alumnos;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese por favor las calificaciones del alumno "<<i+1<<endl;
    
    for(int j=0;j<Calificaciones;j++){
        cout<<"Ingrese por favor la calificacion "<<j+1<<" ";
        cin>>Datos2[j];
        Datos[j+k]=Datos2[j];
    }

k=k+Calificaciones;

}
int h=0;
for(int i=0;i<Alumnos;i++){
    cout<<"Del alumno "<<i+1<<" las calificaciones registradas son:"<<endl;
    suma=0;
    promedio=0;
    
    for(int l=0;l<Calificaciones;l++){
    cout<<Datos[l+h]<<endl;
    suma=suma+Datos[l+h];
    }
    
    promedio=suma/Calificaciones;
    h=h+Calificaciones;

    cout<<"El promedio es de "<<promedio<<endl;
}
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Mi problema es que me da los primeros valores capturados y promedios bien pero en el ultimo valor me da otro numero

Esto es lo que me muestra :

*Ingrese por favor el numero de estudiantes: 3*
*Ingrese por favor el numero de calificaciones por estudiante: 3*
*Ingrese por favor las calificaciones del alumno 1*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 1 10*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 2 10*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 3 10*
*Ingrese por favor las calificaciones del alumno 2*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 1 20*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 2 20*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 3 20*
*Ingrese por favor las calificaciones del alumno 3*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 1 30*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 2 30*
*Ingrese por favor la calificacion 3 30*
*Del alumno 1 las calificaciones registradas son:*
*10*
*10*
*10*
*El promedio es de 10*
*Del alumno 2 las calificaciones registradas son:*
*20*
*20*
*20*
*El promedio es de 20*
*Del alumno 3 las calificaciones registradas son:*
*30*
*30*
*1101004800*
*El promedio es de 3.67002e+008*

Answer (score 3):

En C++ los arrays tienen que tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. Este no es tu caso:

```
int Datos2[Calificaciones]
```

`Calificaciones` es una variable. No se puede conocer su valor hasta que no estás en tiempo de ejecución.

Los arrays cuyo valor se basa en una variable se conocen como VLA (Variable Length Array) y es una característica **no soportada** por el estándar de C++.

Si compila sin errores es porque el compilador ofrece algún tipo de soporte para estas estructuras de datos, pero al no ser parte del estándar es el compilador el que dicta cómo va a funcionar ese código. Esta no suele ser una característica deseable, así que mi recomendación es no usar VLAs.

En su lugar puedes usar memoria dinámica, que para eso está.

Por otro lado, lo que necesitas usar aquí son arrays de dos dimensiones, no arrays de una dimensión.

Tu código está machacando memoria que no pertenece a los arrays todo el rato. No se nota demasiado porque apenas tienes variables

```
for(int i=0;i<Alumnos;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese por favor las calificaciones del alumno "<<i+1<<endl;
    
    for(int j=0;j<Calificaciones;j++){
        cout<<"Ingrese por favor la calificacion "<<j+1<<" ";
        cin>>Datos2[j];
        Datos[j+k]=Datos2[j]; // <--- AQUI
    }

k=k+Calificaciones;

}
```

`Datos`, en tu caso, tiene espacio para 3 elementos, las probabilidades de que `j+k` supere ese valor son ... en fin, es algo que pasa para prácticamente cualquier valor de `i>0`

```
int ** datos = new int*[Alumnos];
for (int i=0; i<Alumnos; i++)
{
    datos[i] = new int[Calificaciones];        
}

for(int i=0;i<Alumnos;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese por favor las calificaciones del alumno "<<i+1<<endl;
    
    for(int j=0;j<Calificaciones;j++){
        cout<<"Ingrese por favor la calificacion "<<j+1<<" ";
        cin>>datos[i][j];
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<Alumnos;i++){
    cout << "Del alumno " << i+1
         << " las calificaciones registradas son:\n";
    suma=0;
    promedio=0;
    
    for(int l=0;l<Calificaciones;l++){
        cout << datos[i][l] << '\n';
        suma=suma+datos[i][l];
    }
    
    promedio=suma/Calificaciones;
    
    cout << "El promedio es de " << promedio << '\n';
}

for(int i=0; i<Alumnos; i++)
    delete[] datos[i];
delete[] datos;
```

Los promedios no arrojan decimales, esa parte ya te la dejo a tí